# Cannot find lpThread library in /usr/lib

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I'm having problems with linking .so libraries. I've already copied them to both `/usr/lib` and `/usr/local/lib`

Below is a snippet of my makefile:

```
PROJ_LDFLAGS += -lpthread

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
    $(CC)  $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(PROJ_LDFLAGS) -o $@

%.o: %.c
    $(CC)  -I. $(CFLAGS) $(PROJ_CFLAGS) -c $<
```

Comment: Copying them is a very bad solution, use  `gcc`'s `-L` switch instead.

Comment: I think with `pthread` you should use `-pthread` instead of `-lpthread`

Comment: I think in addition to using `-lpthread` for linking you also need a `-pthread` flag to use pthreads something on the lines of 
`CFLAGS = -g -Wall -pthread`